# Server isnt recognizing python virtualenv anymore

Tags: django, http, virtualenv, centos7, mod-wsgi

I have a deployed Django app on a Centos 7 server.  I ran into problems when git pulling from my repository.  It doesn't recognize python-home at the location where my virtualenv is anymore.

When i `print(sys.prefix)`, it shows '/usr', but when i activate my virualenv (`source /path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate`) it shows the correct path that is assigned to python-home in my httpd .conf file

.conf file

```
Alias /static /var/www/ek/static
<Directory /var/www/ek/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/ek/new>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIDaemonProcess ek python-path=/var/www/ek python-home= /var/www/kpi_env
WSGIProcessGroup ek
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/ek/new/wsgi.py
```

I'm not exactly sure what the problem is, when im not in my virtualenv, should the prefix be the path to the virtualenv? Should `print(sys.prefix)` only show `var/www/kpi_env` when im in the virtualenv?

Whatever it is, it doesn't recognize `python-home=/var/www/kpi_env` as anything anymore.

When i change it to `python-home = /usr` it works but the application is giving me errors that i've never run into before on my server or on my workstation. This error being `Permission denied is Server running on host 12.0.0.1 and accepting tcp con on port 5432` This is referring to postgresql, and i'm sure that it is running and accepting tcp connection on port 5432. And that my settings.py reflect the right configurations. I havent changed any configurations with changes with `git pull` and havent touched configs for postgresql at all, so i can only think that its because of the python library it is using, because thats the only thing that has changed.

How do i make my httpd server recognize `python-home= /var/www/kpi_env`again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't exactly answer what i asked but this was the workaround i did:

I ran this command to allow my httpd server to accept the connection to my postgresql database,

`setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1`

`-P` will do this permanently and `1` will set it to on.

And in this,  i used `python-home = /usr` since i couldnt get my virtualenv to work anymore